# maximizing memory usage for an MySQL analysis server

Tags: mysql, linux, settings

For an social sciences research project I'm using MySQL (5.5) on a dedicated Linux server with 8 GB of memory. The data consists of some 30 million records, resulting in a MyISAM source table of about 4GB (with MyISAM since the data is stable and transaction are not useful). My question is this: how can I prevent memory from being an unnecessary bottleneck?
At the current settings only about 20% of memory is ever used, but the right balance of my.ini settings is difficult to find, since many variables are interdependent. How can I allow MySQL from using as much memory as possible (reserving enough to prevent Linux from swapping out).

current settings:

```
[mysqld]
max_connections = 3
performance_schema=on
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
local-infile=1

myisam_sort_buffer_size = 2048M

key_buffer_size = 2048M
tmp_table_size = 2048M
max_heap_table_size = 2048M

sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer_size = 256M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 128M
join_buffer_size = 512M
thread_stack = 256KB

query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 32M
table_open_cache= 256
table_definition_cache = 512

myisam_max_sort_file_size = 75G
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to run [MySQL Tuner](http://mysqltuner.com/) on your database after it been running and in use for a while.   No one on SO will be able to give you relevant information for optimizing your memory usage without knowing the shape of your database and usage patterns.   MySQL Tuner automates this.

Comment: I have used both MySQL Tuner and [tuning-primer](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer) with some  success. The problem is that such tools are geared towards transaction servers with a significant number of connections, which leads to warnings about memory usage which don't apply in this situation.